# Shift + cursor stopped behave as usual in org mode

Tags: org-mode, key-bindings

after a package update and restart shift+arrow does not behave as usual in org mode:  move one day up/down in dates or cycling between statuses (todo, done, waiting...) in task lists.

`org-support-shift-select` is `nil`

How can I set again that behaviour, or at least guess where is the issue?

Comment: After what package update? Start Emacs with `emacs -Q` (no init file). Do you then see the same problem? If not ,bisect your init file to find the problem. If you know which package update caused the problem then bisect it to narrow down the problem. Narrow your question accordingly. We can't guess what you broke or how from the vague description you provided.

Answer (score 1):

You can find out which command is bind to a key by `C-h k (your key binding)`. In your case, it would be `C-h k shift-down(or up/left/right)`.

For me, it looks like this:

```
<S-down> runs the command org-shiftdown (found in org-mode-map), which
is an interactive compiled Lisp function in ‘org.el’.

It is bound to <S-down>, <menu-bar> <Org> <TODO Lists> <Priority
Down>, <menu-bar> <Org> <Dates and Scheduling> <Change Date> <1 ...
Earlier>.

(org-shiftdown &optional ARG)

Decrease item in timestamp or decrease priority of current headline.
Calls ‘org-timestamp-down’ or ‘org-priority-down’, or ‘org-next-item’
depending on context.  See the individual commands for more information.

[back]
```

To bind the key to the command you want:

```el
(define-key org-mode-map (kbd "<S-down>") 'the-command-you-want)
(define-key org-mode-map (kbd "<S-up>") 'the-command-you-want)
(define-key org-mode-map (kbd "<S-left>") 'the-command-you-want)
(define-key org-mode-map (kbd "<S-right>") 'the-command-you-want)
```

Related read: [Changing Key Binding](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Changing-Key-Bindings.html)

Comment: Not working the new assignments:  (define-key org-mode-map (kbd "<S-down>") 'org-shiftdown)
(define-key org-mode-map (kbd "<S-up>") 'org-shiftup)
(define-key org-mode-map (kbd "<S-left>") 'org-shiftleft)
(define-key org-mode-map (kbd "<S-right>") 'org-shiftright)  but to no avail even rebooting pc

Comment: What does `C-h k shift-down` display?